# RxJava Call Method When Loop will finish iteration

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-android

I have problem. Solution can be easy but my head is so overheat...

I want to call method ONCE after forEach loop will finish job.

Thanks for any example solution!

```
 override fun saveWorkers(workers: ArrayList<Worker>): Single<Boolean> {
    LogMgr.d(TAG, "saveWorkers() : $workers")

    // remove old workers for current Event Planner and save new
    workers.forEach {
        deleteOldWorkers(it.event_planner_id!!)
                .subscribeOn(getSubscriptionSchedulerForSave())
                .subscribe({ status ->

                }, { error ->

                })
    }

    return Single.create({ emitter ->
        RXModelAdapter.from(Worker::class.java)
                .saveAll(workers)
                .subscribeOn(getSubscriptionSchedulerForSave())
                .subscribe({
                    LogMgr.d(TAG, "saveWorkers() onComplete")
                    emitter.onSuccess(true)

                }, {
                    LogMgr.e(TAG, "saveWorkers() onError ", it)
                    emitter.onError(it)
                })
    })
}
```

1. Proposed sulution

   ```
       Observable.merge(workers.map {
       deleteOldWorkers(it.event_planner_id!!)
   })
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Observable.merge(workers.map { deleteOldWorkers(it.event_planner_id!!) }).doOnComplete()* perhaps?

Comment: Compile error has something to do with 'deleteOldWorkers()' return type. Perhaps you need to define it explicitly. On my side expressions 'val workers = ArrayList<Any>()' and 'Observable.merge( workers.map { Observable.just<Any>(it) } )' do compile alright.